# Should I remove duplicates from a column(Embedding layer input)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, nlp

So say my dataset has two columns: movies watched by a user and genres of these movies.

Example:

User| Movies watched | genres

Movies watched is a list of movieIDs. Ex [1,4,6...] And genres is a string of all the genres of all those movies separated by a space. Ex. "action adventure ...".

Example of the dataset:

User1 | [1,2,5...] | "Adventure comedy adventure action..."

User2 | [1,3,23,24...] | "Adventure documentary action action thriller..."

User3 | [11,21,77...] | "comedy scifi scifi adventure..."

Totally 610 users. That is, 610 rows.

So my input would be, the moviesId list and the genres list.

Note: Total number of movies 9742. Maximum movies watched by any user is 2600. And there are 24 different genres. And a single movie can have multiple genres.

Say I pass these two to an embedding layer. Do I pass the tokenized list after removing duplicate/repeating genres or the tokenized list as it is?

That is, the input would be movieId list of length 2600(padded) and genres list(tokenized) of length(if duplicates are removed) 24, both to two separate embedding layers whose results are concatenated and the next layer would be lstm.

Thankyou!

Comment: When you say duplicates are you talking about combined (movie, genre) duplicates or individual duplicates?

Comment: Just the repeating genres. Since there can be two movies with "action" genre and so on. Totally there are 9742 movies. Maximum movies seen by any user is 2600. So if I do not remove repeated genres, then I'd have a huge genre list input.

Comment: Can you edit your question so that the problem you're trying to solve is clearer. Feels like this depends on what you're trying to achieve with the dataset

Comment: @thushv89 edited my question.. please see..

Comment: So let me see, you have 2600 movie ids and 2600 genres for each user. And you are thinking of removing duplicate genres. For example say you have `[0,1,2,3]` and `[action, action, fantasy, comedy]` then you remove dups and get `[0,2,3]` and `[action, fantasy, comedy]`?

Comment: @thushv89 I'd keep the movieIDs list as it is, just remove the duplicates in the genres list. Assuming movies share same genre. The movieid list has 2600 movieIDs(if users watched less than that, the list will be padded to that length) and 24 unique genres. So if I remove duplicates in a genre list, max length will be 24. Ex. [2,3....567] and [action action fantasy ... ] Then I'd remove duplicates and get [2,3..567] and [action fantasy adventure ....]

Comment: Wouldn't you lose the 1-to-1 correspondence between movies and genres then?

Comment: Yes . But since other users have a different pattern, different set of movies watched, I assumed neural networks would capture the relationship .

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this if 1-to-1 correspondence is an important aspect of your problem. For example if the model is using embeddings from individual movie embedding and genre embedding then mixing them up deeper in the model, then your model will get confused by the removal of duplicates.

Comment: Thankyou! But that would result in genre list of length 6000 approx. Which will be huge.. Any other way to deal with this problem?

Comment: Few things you can do is, cut down the number of timesteps (i.e. 6000) by splitting these to multiple entries (e.g. 600 each). Also, does this need to be a time series problem? Why I'm asking this is if it's a simple movie recommendation problem, you don't need a time aspect in this simple considering 1 movie and 1 genre at a time would suffice.

Comment: @thushv89 But in that case, how do I input multiple movies belonging to different genres so that I get outputs which have a mix of both genres?